# Is there a Notepad++ feature to add some vertical space to the bottom or scroll below last line?

Tags: notepad++

Whenever I'm doing some coding in Notepad++ i need to add some lines at the bottom so if i scroll down, the code doesn't stop at the bottom at the window. The problem is that I sometimes forget to take out the lines :/.

I need to know if there's some kind of plugin or feature that I may have missed that adds some vertical space at the bottom without being actual lines.

Or I have it all wrong and i should just resize the window?

Comment: Is having a little whitespace really that bad? (Unless you're coding in whitespace, of course, then your program's screwed)

Comment: What's wrong with the extra few empty lines?

Comment: they don't show up nicely in version control and while doing compares :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scroll past end of file [plugin has been updated](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/ScrollPastEOF/ScrollPastEOF%201.0U/).

Comment: OMG OMG OMG YES, IT WORKS tyvm sir, how did you find it?  lol

Comment: Unfortunately this plugin has not been updated for Npp 5.9

Comment: This plugin [causes infinite hangs](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/3822/) in newer versions of Notepad++, apparently due to a conflict between it and the 'clickable links' feature. Disabling clickable links (in the MISC. options) lets the plugin work properly.

Comment: @Cameron I am working with it and it is fiine.

Answer (score 9):

There's now (version 7 onwards I think) a setting to enable what you want:

In *Settings > Preferences > Editing*, select 'Enable scrolling beyond last line'.

[image: Enable scrolling beyond last line settings]

Answer (score 0):

What about setting up a macro in Notepad++ ?

Maybe you can record : Ctrl+end, enter, enter, enter, enter etc

Either that or create a batch/shell script that appends blank lines to your file(s)?

Hope this helps

Comment: yeah maybe i can try some autohotkey macro that does it. ty

Comment: @Prozaker Using AHK, you can send some commands directly to the Scintilla component used by NP++. It has an extended (and a bit complex) set of settings for scroll policy that probably allows to do that without changing the text at all.