# Notepad++ scrolls beyond the EOF

Tags: notepad++, scrolling

I updated **Notepad++** to **6.4.3** this morning. Since then, I've noticed a very strange behavior. Notepad++ now scrolls beyond the EOF, i.e. I'm able to scroll the document even beyond the last line.

Here is a screenshot to show what I'm talking about:

[image: Notepad++ scroll image]

Until yesterday, everything was fine and scrolling was not allowed beyond the last line. Suddenly today after updating from version **6.3.3 to 6.4.3**, Notepad++ started behaving in this way.

Is this a new default feature? Can it be disabled through any settings?

Comment: didn't you install any plugins lately?

Comment: Reinstall it! If this still fails then it may be due to a plugin compatibility issue!

Comment: This is common behaviour for most editors if line 35 ends with a CR/LF. Are you sure it's changed behaviour or did a previous instance of the file *not* have a CRLF after line 35?  It would be unusual if you could scroll even further down then line 36, but even that is allowed in some editors (and they will then add empty lines or not).

Comment: What is odd, that I use the same version right here (updated recently too) and I cannot scroll like that, which I would like to be able to do :)

Comment: Do you have the ScrollPastEOF plugin loaded?

Comment: No, I don't have that plugin installed. But I think I figured out the issue. It was the Notepad# plugin which was causing this problem.

Comment: @Alex - You can try the `ScrollPastEOF` as **Oliver** mentioned!

Comment: I really doubt if my question has been answered in [this post](http://superuser.com/q/55863/242743).

Comment: @R.J, yeah, Sorry, I deleted that almost instantly. Got confused a little bit :( And thanks for `ScrollPastEOF` suggestion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was the **Notepad#** plugin which was causing this problem.

I reinstalled Notepad++, and when doing so, it said that the Notepad# plugin would be disabled because of an incompatibility. After doing this I can no longer scroll past the last line in the file.

Answer (score 34):

If you update Notepad++ to version 7.0 or above, you'll now also have the option to enable this natively without plugins:

Go to *Settings* > *Preferences* > *Editing*, and check *Enable scrolling beyond last line*.

Therefore if you see this behaviour on a newer version of Notepad++ and don't want it, you might want to check if that setting is enabled.

Comment: Thanks! Came here for looking how to ENABLE it in 7.5.8!

Comment: This seems to be the preferred solution in my opinion. At this point people really should be using a Notepad++ version above 7.0, and they should also be using a solution that is native / does not rely on a Plugin.

Comment: In my case the setting was activated without my knowledge "over night", no idea why. I had to deactivate it manually.

Answer (score 14):

This behavior should be controlled by the **ScrollPastEOF** plugin.

To remove it, open the **Plugin Manager** and switch to the **Installed** tab. Find the entry for **ScrollPastEOF**, select it and click **Remove**:

[image]

Comment: I think this is also a solution, but it applies if I've installed the **ScrollPastEOF** plugin. My case, it didn't apply actually!

Comment: @R.J: Well, I just updated to 6.4.3 as well and couldn't scroll past the end of the file. The changelist on the download page also didn't mention anything.

Comment: I installed a plugin called `Notepad#`, which had caused this problem. During re-installation, it showed that it was an incompatible plugin and the setup disabled it, which fixed the issue! Anyways `+1`, because I never knew that such a plugin existed just to scroll beyond the EOF!

Comment: I found this page while looking for something like the ScrollPastEOF plugin. Thanks for the answer.